# How to enable Katex in html?

Tags: html, markdown, katex

I'm writing a `markdown` file and compile to `html`,and I'm trying to insert math equations with `Latex` on it.I have tried `Mathjax` but some equations are not supported,so I tried `Katex`.I inserted

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/katex@0.10.0-rc.1/dist/katex.css" integrity="sha384-JwmmMju6Z7M9jiY4RXeJLoNb3aown2QCC/cI7JPgmOLsn3n33pdwAj0Ml/CMMd1W" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script defer src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/katex@0.10.0-rc.1/dist/katex.js" integrity="sha384-atIluo+2Hixq8HCazSQWa1JjeC5L0CQeWAx74Q+EbqgAW4UixbrBQF4+1jvBX01b" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

as what the website says,but when I opened the `html` file the equations were still displayed in `Latex` codes.
what's the right way to insert math equations on html?

Answer (score 1):

KaTeX itself is just a library providing functions to turn LaTeX-like input to HTML / DOM output. To tie that functionality in with the content of the page, you can use additional code such as the contributed [KaTeX auto-render extension](https://katex.org/docs/autorender.html).

Depending on the application, other approaches may be better, so I'd not say this is *the* right way to do it for everybody, but for many applications it is one way of doing it right. Highly dynamic pages where the content constantly changes via Ajax interaction would not work well with the standard configuration of the auto-render extension. For those it would be better to integrate the auto-renderer with the reload machinery.

Pages where the math content is separate from the HTML content might benefit from not bunching the content together with TeX delimiters only to let auto-renderer break them apart again. Instead those pages might feed the math content to the KaTeX render functions directly. Personally I've used this approach with the math content in `<script>` tags, e.g. on [this page](https://gagern.github.io/CindyJS/se/math/2018/08/22/eggbox.html).

Answer (score 1):

You need to include `auto-render.js` in your html

```
<!-- To automatically render math in text elements, include the auto-render extension: -->
<script defer src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/katex@0.10.0-rc.1/dist/contrib/auto-render.min.js" integrity="sha384-kWPLUVMOks5AQFrykwIup5lo0m3iMkkHrD0uJ4H5cjeGihAutqP0yW0J6dpFiVkI" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

and call the render function after the html has loaded

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () { // this need jquery
  renderMathInElement(document.body, {
    // ...options...
    delimiters: [
      { left: "$$", right: "$$", display: true },
      { left: "$", right: "$", display: false },
      { left: "\\[", right: "\\]", display: true }
    ]
  });
});
</script>
```